# How can I label XY pic diagrams, to cite in other parts of my LaTeX file?

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, labels, xy-pic, tikz-knots

I am writing up a project on knot theory, using overleaf, and decided to use XY Pic instead of Tikz as it feels more intuitive.

Is there a way to either attach a label my diagram (to recall/reference later) or enter it into a  math environment?

I've attached a sample of what would need referencing. I cannot place it in a \begin(equation) enviroment and i don't know how to label the entire output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,knot,poly]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

$\langle$$\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.6pc/:}
    [u(0.7)]
    !{\vover}
    !{\vcap-}
    [ul]!{\xcaph@(0)}
    [r]!{\xcaph@(0)}
}$$\rangle = A\langle $$\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.3pc/:}
    [d(0.8)r(1.5)]!{\vcap}
    !{\vcap-}
    !{0;/r0.6pc/:}
    [u(0.5)l]!{\xcaph@(0)}
    !{\vcap-}    [r]!{\xcaph@(0)}
}$$\rangle + A\textsuperscript{-1}\langle $$\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.5pc/:}
    [lu]!{\sbendv}!{\vcap-}
    [r]!{\zbendv}}$$ \rangle$
\newline\hspace*{45pt}
    $=A(-A\textsuperscript{2}-A\textsuperscript{-2})\langle$$\xygraph{
        !{0;/r0.6pc/:}
        !{\xcaph[1]@(0)}
        !{\xcaph[-1]@(1.2)}
        !{\xcaph[1]@(0)}
        }$$\rangle + A\textsuperscript{-1}\langle$$\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.6pc/:}
    !{\xcaph[1]@(0)}
    !{\xcaph[-1]@(1.2)}
    !{\xcaph[1]@(0)}}$$\rangle
\newline\hspace*{45pt}=-A\textsuperscript{3}\langle$$\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.5pc/:}
    !{\xcaph[2]@(0)}
    }$$\rangle
$



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try an `aligned` environment from `amsmath` inside an `equation`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,knot,poly]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
\langle\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.6pc/:}
    [u(0.7)]
    !{\vover}
    !{\vcap-}
    [ul]!{\xcaph@(0)}
    [r]!{\xcaph@(0)}
}\rangle &= A \langle \xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.3pc/:}
    [d(0.8)r(1.5)]!{\vcap}
    !{\vcap-}
    !{0;/r0.6pc/:}
    [u(0.5)l]!{\xcaph@(0)}
    !{\vcap-}    [r]!{\xcaph@(0)}
}\rangle + A^{-1}\langle\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.5pc/:}
    [lu]!{\sbendv}!{\vcap-}
    [r]!{\zbendv}}\rangle 
\\
    &=A(-A^2 - A^{-2}) \langle\xygraph{
        !{0;/r0.6pc/:}
        !{\xcaph[1]@(0)}
        !{\xcaph[-1]@(1.2)}
        !{\xcaph[1]@(0)}
        }\rangle + A^{-1}\langle\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.6pc/:}
    !{\xcaph[1]@(0)}
    !{\xcaph[-1]@(1.2)}
    !{\xcaph[1]@(0)}}\rangle
\\
    &=-A^{3}\langle\xygraph{
    !{0;/r0.5pc/:}
    !{\xcaph[2]@(0)}
    }\rangle
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```